# Trying to list user favourities from API, getting "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'firebase.auth().currentUser.uid')

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am creating an App (React Native) which is connecting to API and allowing user to add object recieved from API to its favourities. I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsZH-YG_JL4) but I am getting yellow warning "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejsction (id:0): TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'firebase.auth().currentUser.uid'). Data is adding to database but it is not listing (showing) in my app.

Home.js (in which I want my favorities to be listed)

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {Container, Content, ListItem} from 'native-base';

var data = []
var currentUser

class Home extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
   super(props)

    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged:(r1,r2) => r1 !==r2})

    this.state = {
        listViewData : data
    }
}
componentDidMount(){

    this.getPlants()
}

getPlants = async()=>{

    currentUser = await firebase.auth().currentUser

    var that = this

    firebase.database().ref(currentUser.uid).child('plantList').on('child_added',function(data){

        var newData = [...that.state.listViewData]
        newData.push(data)

        that.setState({ listViewData: newData})
    })
}
render(){
 return(
<Container style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
                <Content>
                    <ListView
                        enableEmptySections
                        dataSource = {this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.listViewData)}
                        renderRow={data =>

                            <ListItem>
                                <Text> {data.val().namePlant}</Text>
                            </ListItem>
                        }
                    />
                </Content>
            </Container>
     );}
}

export default Home;
```

App.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("mail@gmail.com","password")

...

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
super(props);

    if (!firebase.apps.length) { firebase.initializeApp(config.FirebaseConfig); }
}
  render() {

    return <AppContainer  />;
  }
}
```

Plant.js (which is printing printing data of particular object from API and adding it to database)

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

var currentUser
class CatalogPlant extends React.Component {

  addToFavourites = async(scname) =>{

//get current user
currentUser = await firebase.auth().currentUser

//get unique key
var databaseRef = await firebase.database().ref(currentUser.uid).child('plantList').push()

//update plant name at the unique key
databaseRef.set({
  'namePlant': scname

})


  }

// part of code which connects to API and gets the data...
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This includes removing anything that isn't needed to reproduce the problem, since that isn't relevant to the error. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your user is not signed in to the app yet. In that case `firebase.auth().currentUser` is `null`, so when you do `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`, you are calling `uid` on `null`.

The simple way to fix this is to always check for `null` after calling `firebase.auth().currentUser`. So:

```
currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser

if (currentUser != null) {
    var that = this

    firebase.database().ref(user.uid).child('plantList').on('child_added',function(data){

    ...
```

Note that I also removed the `await` from before `firebase.auth().currentUser`. Since `firebase.auth().currentUser` is not an asynchronous operation, there no need (nor use) for `await` here.

The better solution is to use an auth state listener, as also shown in this example from the [RNFirebase documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/getting-started):

> ```
> componentDidMount() {
>   this.unsubscriber = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
>     this.setState({ user });
>   });
> }
> ```

So in your case that would translate to:

```
componentDidMount(){
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

    if (user != null) {
      var that = this

       firebase.database().ref(currentUser.uid).child('plantList').on('child_added',function(data){

          var newData = [...that.state.listViewData]
          newData.push(data)

          that.setState({ listViewData: newData})
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Signing in, or restoring the authentication state when the app restarts, is an asynchronous operation. So simply calling `firebase.auth().currentUser` may miss the fact that the user signed in. By using `onAuthStateChanged`, Firebase will call your code whenever the authentication state changes, which is the perfect moment to do things that depend on authentication state, such as (in your case) listening for data for that user).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have replaced my code with yours but now I am getting a red error "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'currentUser.uid'".

Comment: Yeah, that was a copy/paste mistake in my code. I fixed it in my answer.